# How to add a class to the first child elements in each set using jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover

I wish to add a class to the first element in each set of elements. But my JS is applying to the first set only.

The attempt is to add a class to the first element of a set when the document loads and removes that class on hover.

**HTML**

```
<div id="mega-menu-container">
   <div id="mega-menu">
      <div class="menu-title active"><h4>.....</h4></div>
      <div class="menu-title"><h4>.....</h4></div>
      <div class="menu-title"><h4>.....</h4></div>
      <div class="menu-title"><h4>.....</h4></div>
      <div class="menu-title"><h4>.....</h4></div>
   </div>
   <div id="mega-menu">
      <div class="menu-title"><h4>.....</h4></div>
      <div class="menu-title"><h4>.....</h4></div>
      <div class="menu-title"><h4>.....</h4></div>
      <div class="menu-title"><h4>.....</h4></div>
      <div class="menu-title"><h4>.....</h4></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mega-menu-container .menu-title').eq(0).addClass('active');

$('#mega-menu-container .menu-title h4').hover(function(){
    $('#mega-menu-container .menu-title').toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
});
$("#mega-menu-container .menu-title h4").mouseleave(function(){
    $('#mega-menu-container .menu-title').eq(0).addClass('active');
});
});
})(jQuery);
```

**PROBLEM**

The problem is - the class "**active**" is added on the first div `menu-title` in the first set but not in the second set, as you can see in the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[:first-child](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)** selector to selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.:

```
$('#mega-menu-container .menu-title:first-child').addClass('active');
```

You need to also fix hover events to target only closest relevant elements and not all. You can use current element context `this` along with traversing to target other h4 elements .

Comment: Excellent. So dumb I was using only :first and never thought of :first-child. Thanks for this. And also thanks for the advice. Will improve the codes now.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this by CSS without any jquery. Lets say your active css is changing color to green or what ever. Mean while whole set is red. then you could do as [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H8jCm/90/)

Here I am using `#mega-menu > :first-child`

Comment: Thanks. Actually the class .active is not added manually. It's done with .addClass() dynamically to each first element of a set. The same is also removed on hover on child elements. So I think CSS alone cannot help me here.